# Emacs lisp: get sub-matches from a regexp match

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a string variable somewhere in elisp code, and want to extract some parts of it into other variables using a regular expression with groupings. That's something that you can write in 1-2 lines in any language:

`my ($user, $domain) = $email =~ m/^(.+)@(.+)$/;`

How do I write the same in elisp?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
(save-match-data ; is usually a good idea
  (and (string-match "\\`\\([^@]+\\)@\\([^@]+\\)\\'" email)
       (setq user (match-string 1 email)
             domain (match-string 2 email) ) ))
```

The [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Match-Data.html#Match-Data) is your friend. See also http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook

Comment: That worked, thank you! Take my word: I did try reading the cookbook before asking, but didn't come up with the recipe in a reasonable time :-)

Comment: Is there an easy way to translate the Perl regexp (mentioned in breqwas's question) to emacs regexp you mentioned?

Comment: @aartist: replacing `.+` with `[^@]+` is a correctness fix which should be applied to the Perl regex, too. The Emacs backslash-quotes I used properly correspond to `\A` and `\Z` in Perl. In general, Perl has a much richer set of regex extensions, and Emacs has a few specialties such as its `\s` syntax character classes, so not all regular expressions can be straightforwardly converted. Post a separate question if you want details.

Comment: For what it's worth, I added this to the EmacsWiki Elisp Cookbook page also.

Comment: What is with the lone backtick and single quote?

Comment: @Coyo Those are beginning of string and end of string anchors in Emacs regex, like `\A` and `\Z` in Perl (and thus also many other modern regex dialects). Probably read the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html)